# PHP+MySql : select row by like ( with and without space )

Tags: php, mysql

My table :

```
Mohammad
Ali
Moham mad
m Ohammad
Reza
Nasser
Mohamma d
```

I want select from this table and return all name of *mohammad* even use space or not use space

Like :

```
select * from table where name like '%mohammad%' 
// i want return Mohammad,Moham mad,m Ohammad,Mohamma d
```

Also :

```
select * from table where name like '%Mohamma d%' 
// i want return Mohammad,Moham mad,m Ohammad,Mohamma d
```

And :

```
select * from table where name like '%Moham mad%' 
// i want return Mohammad,Moham mad,m Ohammad,Mohamma d
```

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/sql/character-functions/trim.php

Comment: Can help me more ?

Comment: What do you want when the name is `Chris` and your db has `chris`, `christine`, `christian`, `chrissy`, `christy`, etc.

Comment: No, i want if search Mohammad and in db has moh ammad, mo ha mmad , etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from table where REPLACE(name,' ','') like '%mohammad%'
```